# How insert matched words from strings in dynamic code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem

Im building JS code that can:

1. Create an array from `sentences` in `div`
2. Extract `key words` from each `string`
3. Put key words in proper position to execute code dynamically.

```js
//Hocus Pocus
//A function just transformed the sentences from .sendToJS in the HTML to an array like this

sentences = [
  ".box1 is click, change background to green",
  ".box2 is dblclick, change height to 200px",
  ".box3 is hover, change border to red",
  ".box4 is click, change border-radius to 20px",
  ".box5 is click, change transition to .3s",
]

sentences.forEach(function(s, i) {
  Broken = /(^.+?(?=,))(,\s)(.*)/g.exec(s)
  a = Broken[1]
  b = Broken[3]

  c = /(.*) is (\w+$)/g.exec(a)
  d = /(\w+ )(.*)( to )(.*)$/.exec(b)
  who = "'" + c[1] + "'" //example .box1
  evt = "'" + c[2] + "'" //example click
  change = "'" + d[2] + "'" //example background
  to = "'" + d[4] + "'" //example green

  //For some reason I can't get this part to work
  //I have everything necessary for it to work… yet it will not work
  $(who).on(evt, function() {
    $(who).css(change, to)
    console.log('executed')
  });



});
```

```css
body {
  background: #E7F0F6;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sendToJS {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.boxes {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s;
}

.boxes:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0px 0px 1px #36BCFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sendToJS">
  If .box1 is clicked, change background to green. If .box2 is dblclicked, change height to 200px. If .box3 is hovered, change border to red. If .box4 is clicked, change border-radius to 20px. If .box5 is clicked, change transition to .3s.
</div>

<div class="boxes box1"></div>
<div class="boxes box2"></div>
<div class="boxes box3"></div>
<div class="boxes box4"></div>
<div class="boxes box5"></div>
```

**Dynamic Code**

takes key words that has been extracted from sentences.

```
$(who).on(evt, function(){
    $(who).css(change, to)
    console.log('executed')
});
```

**Example of it being executed**

```
$('.box1').on('click', function(){
    $('.box1').css('background', 'green')
    console.log('executed')
});
```

Comment: "Example of it being executed" - how do you know _that_ is what's being executed, and not, say, `$("'.box1'").css("'background'", "'green'")`?

Comment: I only want it to say… `$('.box1').css('background', 'green')`

Comment: Well… that's an example of how all of them should look.

Comment: "should look", right. But not "what is actually being executed". Big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add single quotes around all your extracted values. You also didn't declare your variables.

`hover` is not a valid event, use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately for scripting.

Fixed code:

```js
//Hocus Pocus
//A function just transformed the sentences from .sendToJS in the HTML to an array like this

var sentences = [
  ".box1 is click, change background to green",
  ".box2 is dblclick, change height to 200px",
  ".box3 is mouseenter, change border to 3px solid red",
  ".box3 is mouseleave, change border to none",
  ".box4 is click, change border-radius to 20px",
  ".box5 is click, change transition to .3s"
];
sentences.forEach(function(s, i) {
  var broken = /(^.+?(?=,))(,\s)(.*)/g.exec(s);
  var a = broken[1];
  var b = broken[3];

  var c = /(.*) is (\w+$)/g.exec(a);
  var d = /(\w+ )(.*)( to )(.*)$/.exec(b);
  var who = c[1]; //example .box1
  var evt = c[2]; //example click
  var change = d[2]; //example background
  var to = d[4]; //example green

  //For some reason I can't get this part to work
  //I have everything necessary for it to work… yet it will not work
  $(who).on(evt, function() {
    $(who).css(change, to);
    console.log('executed');
  });



});
```

```css
body {
  background: #E7F0F6;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sendToJS {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.boxes {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s;
}

.boxes:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0px 0px 1px #36BCFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sendToJS">
  If .box1 is clicked, change background to green. If .box2 is dblclicked, change height to 200px. If .box3 is hovered, change border to red. If .box4 is clicked, change border-radius to 20px. If .box5 is clicked, change transition to .3s.
</div>

<div class="boxes box1"></div>
<div class="boxes box2"></div>
<div class="boxes box3"></div>
<div class="boxes box4"></div>
<div class="boxes box5"></div>
```

Comment: `red` is not a valid value for the CSS `border` property. It should be `1px solid red` or similar.

Comment: Actually `hover` is not a valid event. Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately for scripting.